# Switch for two different supplies

Tags: electrical, switch

Would it be safe to use a three way switch to run two different hots to one outlet. Our RV is 30 amp, with two A/C’s. Both running they pull 24 amps, so one has to be shut off for the microwave. I can get a separate 20 amp supply most times we stop. The switch is rated 20 amps. Is there another way?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Hope you found the answer helpful. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Hold on.  How does your RV plug into utility power? Does it use a TT30 connector (3-pin) or a 14-30 (4-pin) plug?  Are the air conditioners 240V? If a 14-30, we just need to rearrange your panel.  Also, can you post a photo of the service panel inside the RV?

Comment: Yes, how does your RV plug into utility power, and can you post photos of your panel?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is ordinary switches only switch hot, but with a second source you need to switch neutral to go to that source as well.

One possible fix is to wire up a separate inlet outside wired to one receptacle inside and move the microwave plug between the "main" receptacle and this new dedicated secondary supply when needed.

Comment: +1.  For completeness, I'll point out that you can get double pole double throw switches, which would allow switching out the neutral at the same time, but I think your solution with just moving the plug is better.